# build.gradle on project level has a new format in Android. How to change my existing gradle setup to a new one?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I noticed the build.gradle of project level has a new format:

**FROM:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
        ext.retrofit_version = "2.6.0"
        ext.coroutines_version = "1.3.0"
        ext.room_version = '2.4.2'
        ext.glide_version = "4.8.0"
        ext.nav_version = '2.4.2'
        ext.daggerVersion = '2.14.1'
    
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**TO:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

The settings.gradle has a different format as well. It looks like, it needs to move repositories, etc from build.gradle to here.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would think that there's really no need to change to the new way. If it works, it works. And I don't think they will deprecate the old way any time soon, and if they do, then they probably also add some automated way to migrate it for you. But that's just my opinion

Comment: Ahh, so it is not mandatory to change it for now. Thanks @IvoBeckers